# Install Bootstrap 5.0.0. Alpha 2 from package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, bootstrap-5

Here's what I have in my current package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

But I would like to run the latest Bootstrap version, which is 5.0.0. Alpha 2. How do I indicate that according to package.json syntax?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: to specify bootstrap 5.0.0 Alpha 2 in your package.json do this

```
"bootstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha2",
```

Comment: No, I want to install Bootstrap 5 alpha straight from the package.json, so when I run npm install I'm all set.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. Please read my comment.

Comment: Sorry, made a final edit to my answer. - Is that not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the Bootstrap version you want using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/):

```
npm install bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha2
```